# Searching for string in text file and writing on the same line as this string

Tags: python, file-handling

I am writing a simple arithmetic quiz. My aim is to store the score and name of the participants to a text file, however if they have already taken the test before then the score should be appended to the same line as their name is on. This is my code:

```
src = open("Class {} data.txt".format(classNo),"a+",)
for line in src:
    if surname.lower() in line:
        print("yes")
        # score should be written on same line as the surname is in the txt fileS
        src.write(score)
    else:
        print("nope")

src.close()
```

However there is no evidence that python has executed the if statement as neither "yes", nor "nope" has been printed and the text file remains the same.

Comment: use a dict and pickle then you can easily look up a name also

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I was trying to avoid pickling because this is school work and I need to keep it simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("Class {} data.txt".format(classNo),"a+",) as src:
    lines = src.readlines() # all lines are stored here
    for ind,line in enumerate(lines):
        if surname.lower() in line:
            print("yes")
            # score should be written on same line as the surname is in the txt fileS
            lines[ind] = "{} {}\n".format(line.rstrip(), score) # add first or new scores 
        else:
            print("nope")
    with open("Class {} data.txt".format(classNo),"w",) as src: # reopen and write updated lines
        src.writelines(lines)
```

Or use fileinput.input with `inplace=True`:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("Class {} data.txt".format(classNo),inplace=True):
    if surname.lower() in line:
        print("{} {}".format(line.rstrip(), score))
    else:
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: When opening for the second time in write mode wouldn't all the existing data be overwritten

Comment: no worries, I prefer the first solution too, I just said I would show you an alternative

Comment: is it possible to have multiple scores on the same line, as solution 1 would update it with the latest score - or would it? Im unsure